# Result of a function as a parameter of other function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I was reading about callback functions and it seems easy but I still don't know how to do, what I want to.

I have a form where you put weight and height and depending of these variables, it prints some amount. But there is also third variable, let's say width, and if width is less than 50, I want it to print this amount plus 30.

I think the function width is wrong, but I can't solve it. Could you help?

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {
  let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  let height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  let width = document.getElementById('width').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = weightAndHeight(weight, height);
}

function weightAndHeight(weight, height) {
  if (weight <= 50) {
    if (height < 20) {
      return '100';
    } else if (height >= 20 && height < 100) {
      return '200';
    }
  }
}


function width(width, weightAndHeight) {
  if (width < 50) {
    weightAndHeight += 30;
  }
}
```

```html
Weight: <input type="number" id="weight" /><br/> Height: <input type="number" id="height" /><br/> Widht: <input type="number" id="width" /><br/>

<button type="button" id="submit">Calculate</button>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, but FWIW you're playing a bit fast and loose with reusing container names (for instance the function `width` takes an arg called `width` and an arg called `weightAndHeight` which is the same name of a different function).  It may work, but I'd be concerned that at some point it will yield unexpected results that will be very difficult to trace and resolve...

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {
  let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  let height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  let width = document.getElementById('width').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = fnc2(width, fnc1(weight, height));
}

function fnc1(weight, height, width) {
  if (weight <= 50) {
    if (height < 20) return 100;
    else if (height >= 20 && height < 100) return 200;
  }else return 0;
}

function fnc2(width, val) {
  if (width < 50) return val + 30;
  return val;
}
```

```html
Weight: <input type="number" id="weight" /><br/> Height: <input type="number" id="height" /><br/> Widht: <input type="number" id="width" /><br/>

<button type="button" id="submit">Calculate</button>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to do it in separate functions :) There will be also other variables, so I think the code would be more readable in a few functions.

Comment: Functions separated

Answer (score 0):

```
function result() {
    let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    let height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    let width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    const weightAndHeight = weightAndHeight(weight, height);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = width(weight, weightAndHeight);
}
```

If to make some extra efforts, you can use **function chaining**. In this case object should be created with all required functions. Each function should return `this`. Finally you can get something like:

```
class SizeCalculator {
    constructor() {
        this.size = 0;
    }
    weightAndHeight(weight, height) {
        .... // update this.size
        return this;
    }
    width(width) {
        .... // update this.size
        return this;
    }
    length(length) {
        .... // update this.size
        return this;
    }
}

let size = new SizeCalculator()
    .weightAndHeight(weight, height)
    .width(width)
    .length(length)
    .size;
```

More detailed is below:
https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/understanding-method-chaining-in-javascript-647a9004bd4f - good explanation about method chaining and callbacks

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure it solves my problem, because there will be also other variables, let's say "depth" and if depth is less than 50, also add 30. That's why I think, that innerHTML should equal to function weightAndHeight. It's basic here and other variables will change results only in some cases.